# Query Master Detail with limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, named `t_master` and `t_detail`.

The data in the `t_detail` table corresponds to a record on the master table.

Data of `t_master`:

| ID | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | Toyota |
| 2. | Honda |

Data for the `t_detail`:

| DetID | ParentID | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 1 | Corona |
| 2. | 1 | Corolla |
| 3. | 1 | Altis |
| 4. | 2 | Civic |
| 5. | 2 | Jazz |

Now, I want to make a query that should select all rows in the master table and at the same time, select the detail which only show with limit 2 row, as in:

| No | ID Brand | DetID | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 1 | 1 | Corona |
| 3. | 1 | 2 | Corolla |
| 4. | 2 | 1 | Civic |
| 5. | 2 | 2 | Jazz |

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your latest coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want per group. Then, filtering rows out is easy. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    d.detid as no,
    m.id as id_brand,
    row_number() over(partition by m.id order by d.detid) as detid,
    d.model
  from t_master m
  join t_detail d on d.parentid = m.id
) x
where detid <= 2
```

Result:

```
 no  id_brand  detid  model   
 --- --------- ------ ------- 
 1   1         1      Corona  
 2   1         2      Corolla 
 4   2         1      Civic   
 5   2         2      Jazz
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=578c5ea4110381540371e983a6c59358).

Comment: @methos Fixed the typo.